# Jquery ajax not working properly with django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

Here I am trying to add category with ajax but it is not working properly. It creates the data but it doesn't display. I want to display this data in the HTML page without a refresh. In the template, categories come from the database. I want to display the newly created category in the option without refresh after saving the data.

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit','#=category-form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: {
                name:$('#name').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(){
                 $("#myModal").modal("hide");

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

views

```
class AddgoryCateView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        category = Category.objects.create(name=name)
        data = {'category': category}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

template

```
    <label class="text-primary">Categories</label> 
&nbsp;<small><i class="ic-add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i></small>

                       <select class="form-control" name="categories" multiple="multiple" id="id-categories">
                        {% for category in categories %}
                           <option value="{{category.pk}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
```

Comment: what does the server returns back ? Here put `success :function(data){` and do a `console.log(data)` to see what comes in data.

Comment: if you are getting new options in success, then you can update the dropdown, $('#id').html(data);

Comment: @AhmedSunny in console i got the right data but it is not appearing in my select option

Comment: you need to create options in js in a loop , then append it